# How to resolve the "sed: unmatched '/'" error

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to run the following command on a groovy script which will then run on Jenkins:

```
def sedCmd = cat sample.txt | sed -n -e /word id=123/,/end id = 123/ p
def logs = sedCmd.execute()
```

The file "sample.txt" looks like this:

```
Thurs 20 Sep 2018 word id=123
The cat 
In the hat
Bla bla
Thurs 20 Sep 2018 end id=123
Test
```

When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
sed: unmatched '/'
```

I tested the same command locally on my terminal with a small minor changes, and it works as it should:

```
cat sample.txt | sed -n -e '/word id=123/,/end id = 123/ p'
```

Comment: Did you use the single quotes in your `sedCmd` definition as well? And, you know that `cat` is not needed as `sed` can read files on its own?

Comment: No I haven't used it. In groovy script, I've encapsulated all in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have much better luck executing a list than a single string:

```groovy
def sedCmd = ["sed", "-n", "/word id=123/,/end id=123/ p", "sample.txt"]
def process = sedCmd.execute()
process.waitFor()
process.err.readLines().each {line -> println "Err: $line"}
process.in.readLines().each  {line -> println "Out: $line"}
```

```
Out: Thurs 20 Sep 2018 word id=123
Out: The cat 
Out: In the hat
Out: Bla bla
Out: Thurs 20 Sep 2018 end id=123
```

Comment: Hi @glenn, the probelem with groovy script is that its attempting to match the first forward slash. I tried to backlash it but that didn't work either

Comment: what? the forward slashes are sed's way of quoting a regular expression. If it's not working, show the error messages.